# Send my private key through the ssh session only

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

My scenario:

```
localhost: contains my private key
serverA: contains my public key
serverB: contains my public key
```

I login to *serverA* and perform some operations, which involve copying some files from *serverB*. Since I login with a common username, I don't want to have my private key stored in the *serverA*. This means, in the ideal situation, I would be able to **send my private key only through the ssh session** and make it available just as `ssh-agent` does, so then I connect from *serverA* to the *serverB*, my private key is read from memory and used to authenticate to *serverB*. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's what the `ssh -A` flags does.

This only works with keys already added to a running `ssh-agent` on your *local* machine. If you have to enter your passphrase when you connect to `serverA` (or just use a passphrase-free key) then this isn't going to work

From the man page:

> **-A**
> Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.
>
> Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the  agent's  UNIX-domain  socket) can  access  the  local agent through the forwarded connection.  An attacker cannot obtain key material from the agent, however they can perform operations on the keys that enable them to authenticate using the identities loaded into the agent.
>
> **-a**
> Disables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.

You might want to pay attention to the warning in the quote though. `-A` does not expose your key, but it does allow anybody with read/write access to the ssh-agent socket *on the server* to use your credentials, if they know where to look for the socket. Since you log in using a common user then anybody else with access to that user can get access to *your* agent.

I think the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on the server just forwards traffic direct to the ssh-agent running on your *local* machine.

Comment: I have to confess I tried it, but only by giving my passpharse while connecting. Then I realised I had to setup the ssh agent so that a socket could be established (the key itself isn't forwarded).

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer